# Get files from FormData object in laravel 5.8 sent over via Axios in Vue

Tags: ajax, file-upload, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.8

I have a `Laravel & Vue` application where I want to upload files along with other data via `axios` but when I send the form, I do not see the files there in `laravel`.

Here is my `HTML` form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm()">
                <h5 class="card-title">Add a new Discount</h5>
                <p class="text-danger mb-3 font" style="font-size: 12px" >Required fields are marked with *</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                        <InputField v-model="form.amount" classes="form-control" name="amount"
                                    placeholder="Discount amount here (required)" type="number"
                                    label="Discount Amount* : "
                                    @update:field="form.amount = $event" required="required"
                        />
                        <p class="error-field" id="erramount"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                        <label for="student_name"><small><b>Student Name:</b></small></label>
                        <input :value="student.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="student_name" disabled>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                        <label for="batchfee"><small><b>Batch Fee (Max Discount)</b></small></label>
                        <input :value="student.fee" type="text" class="form-control" id="batchfee" disabled>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                        <label for="file"><small><b>Select File*:</b></small></label>
                        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" @change="setFile" multiple>

                        <p class="error-field" id="errattachments"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2" v-for="bm in bmonths">
                        <label><small><b>{{ bm.month }}-{{bm.year}}</b></small></label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" @change="addBmonth(bm.id)" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-5">Save</button>
            </form>
```

Here is my `Vue` data :

```
data(){
    return {

        form: {
            'amount': null,
            'student_id': null,
            'batchId': null,
            'batchfee': null,
            'attachments': null,
            'selectedBmonths': [],
        },
        student: null,
        bmonths: [],

        errors: null,


    }
},
```

Here is the `setFile` method which is called by `@change` event on the file uploader:

```
setFile(event)
    {
        this.form.attachments = new FormData();
        this.form.attachments.append('files', event.target.files);
    }
```

Here is the `submitForm` method that is called on `submit` of the `form`:

```
submitForm()
    {
        this.clearErrors();

        this.form.student_id = this.student.stdId;
        this.form.batchId = this.student.batchId;
        this.form.batchfee = parseInt(this.student.fee);
        this.form.amount = parseInt(this.form.amount);

        axios.post('/university/api/discounts', this.form)
            .then(response => {
                //this.$router.push('/university/discounts/' + response.data.id);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                this.errors = errors.response.data.errors;
                console.log(errors);
                for(const key in this.form)
                {
                    if(this.errors && this.errors[key] && this.errors[key].length > 0)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('err' + key).innerHTML = this.errors[key][0];
                    }
                }
            });
    },
```

Here is the `laravel` function that just returns the `request()` for checking and seeing if the files were sent correctly:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return request();
}
```

When I see the result in the `console.log()`, I see an empty `attachments` array:

[image: console.log output]

Any help is appreciated in advance.

**EDIT**
I still have not found any solution for this, please help me overcome this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue 0 : `this.form.amount` must be moved out of `this.form`.

**Solution :** In order to fix *issue 1*, we are going to assume it was moved to `this.amount`.

### Issue 1 : `FormData` cannot be used inside `JSON`.

**Solution A :** use `FormData` instead of `JSON`.

```js
this.form = new FormData();
this.form.append('student_id', this.student.stdId);
this.form.append('batchId', this.student.batchId);
this.form.append('batchfee', parseInt(this.student.fee));
this.form.append('amount', parseInt(this.amount));
```

**Solution B** : use stringified `JSON` inside `FormData`.

```js
this.form = new FormData();
this.form.append(
    '', // <-- choose a key here
    JSON.stringify({
        student_id: this.student.stdId,
        batchId: this.student.batchId,
        batchfee: parseInt(this.student.fee),
        amount: parseInt(this.amount)
    })
);
```

### Issue 2 : `append` must be called for each file with using a key ending with `[]`.

**Solution :** loop over the files.

```js
for(const file of event.target.files)
    this.form.append('files[]', file);
```

### Additional info

- You no longer need to initialize `this.form` as an object as it would always be overwritten.
- You may initialize `this.student` as an object for clarity.

Comment: I implemented your method but I am now getting the error in the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913580/getting-image-validation-error-despite-sending-image-via-axios-in-vue

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge is limited to `axios` and `FormData`. Please feel free to ask for more details on that if needed, or mark my answer as accepted. However, I am inexperienced with Laravel so I won't be able to answer your new question.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I +1 your comment and answer and accepted your answer. Thanks for the efforts.