# Getting Image Validation Error Despite Sending Image Via Axios in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file-upload, axios, laravel-validation

I am working on a `laravel 5.8 and vue 2` application where I am sending images through `axios` but I get `file must be an image` error despite sending image.

Here is my `uploader`:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple class="form-control" 
        @change="setFile">
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my `vue data object`:

```
data(){
    return {
        form: new FormData,
        amount: null,
        selectedBmonths: [],
        student: null,
        bmonths: [],
        result: null,

        errors: null,


    }
},
```

Here is the `setFile` method that adds images to the `FormData`:

```
setFile(event)
    {
        for(const file of event.target.files)
            this.form.append('files[]', file);
    }
```

Here is the `submitForm` method that submits the form:

```
submitForm()
    {
        this.clearErrors();

        this.form.append('student_id', this.student.stdId);
        this.form.append('batchId', this.student.batchId);
        this.form.append('batchfee', this.student.fee);
        this.form.append('amount', this.amount);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedBmonths.length; i++) 
        {
            this.form.append('selectedBmonths[]', this.selectedBmonths[i]);
        }

        const config = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }};
        axios.post('/university/api/discounts', this.form, config)
            .then(response => {
                //this.$router.push('/university/discounts/' + response.data.id);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                this.errors = errors.response.data.errors;
                console.log(this.errors);
                for(const key in this.form)
                {
                    if(this.errors && this.errors[key] && this.errors[key].length > 0)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('err' + key).innerHTML = this.errors[key][0];
                    }
                }
            });
    },
```

Here is the `Laravel Validation` function in controller:

```
private function validateData()
{
    return request()->validate(
        [
            'batchId' => 'required|integer',
            'batchfee' => 'required|integer',
            'amount' => 'required|integer|lte:batchfee',
            'student_id' => 'required|integer',
            'selectedBmonths' => 'nullable|array',
            'files.*' => 'image',
        ],
        [
            'amount.lte' => 'Discount should be less than or equal to the batch fee.',
        ]
    );
}
```

When I `submit` the `form`, I get the following error messages:

[image: errors]

**Note: As you can see, I have set the right headers/config as well but still I get the image validation error messages.**

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: remove the validation and `dd($request->all())` to see that you are sending string(name of the file) and not the files themselves to the server. Check examples of how to append a file to a formData `formData.append('userpic', myFileInput.files[0], 'test.jpg');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#examples

Comment: Are you getting images on laravel side? could you check with dd($request)?

Answer (score 1):

I prepared the same environment as yours and tested it. I got the same error messages. It only works for png files. But I use [mime](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimes) validation instead of
using [image](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-image) validation, it works.

My validation:

```php
return request()->validate(
    [
        'files.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
    ]
);
```

My javascript (almost same as yours):

```js
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        const that = this
        this.form.append('text', this.text)
        const config = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        axios.post('/file/test', this.form, config).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    },
    setFile (e) {
        for(const file of event.target.files) {
            this.form.append('files[]', file)
        }
    }
},
```

And also, I think it will be better to add `accept` attribute to the input, like:

```html
<input type="file" multiple @change="setFile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg">
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I changed the `image` validation rule to `required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png` but I still get the same error messages